# run psql commands in docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, psql

I have a docker compose file, which spins up postgres db. How can I run some psql commands after this container is started?

[image]

This is what I'm trying to run:

createuser postgres

createdb DB

createdb TEST_DB

psql -d DB -c "GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE "DB" TO postgres"

psql -d DB -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp""

psql -d DB -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pg_trgm""

psql -d TEST_DB -c "GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE "TEST_DB" TO postgres"

psql -d TEST_DB -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp""

psql -d TEST_DB -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pg_trgm""

Comment: Please share your code as the plain text format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) image supports initialization scripts, you can save your commands in .sql file in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and they will be executed

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived
> from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (creating the directory if necessary).
> After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user
> and database, it will run any *.sql files, run any executable *.sh
> scripts, and source any non-executable *.sh scripts found in that
> directory to do further initialization before starting the service.

Answer (score 0):

postgres image initialization scripts did it!
I used COPY in my Dockerfile to copy some .sh files to the container.